# Changing the frequency response of an open loop circuit op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency-response, loop-gain

Usually on the frequency response of an open loop op amp, the gain decrease greatly in the higher frequencies. How can we increase the gain from 50 hz to 25 khz to remain high at, say, 120 dB?

The reason is I want to make a noise generator as an additional sound effect after seeing some circuit bend pedals on several electric guitar effect-related forums.

Comment: wait, is this about an open-loop opamp *circuit configuration*, or about the opamp in itself? I.e., do you want to take a fixed opamp and have it in a higher-bandwidth circuit, or are you designing an opamp for the purpose of this question?

Comment: It is the former. But you bring in about the opamp in itself, is it possible to do the same to the opamp itself?

Comment: you will have to. Because if your circuit is open-loop, there's nothing you can do to increase gain beyond what the opamp in itself can do.

Comment: So what are the possible ways to increase the gain of frequencies from 50 hz to 25 khz with an opamp with a very high open loop gain of 150 dB? If we can't do that with an open loop circuit, then what should we do? Using different op amps?

Comment: Uff, good question. Since using opamps in an open loop configuration is unusual to begin with, I'll go with: this is probably a real problem, and you'll need to describe your whole application in more detail. This quickly becomes a question of stability, sensitivity and so on. Notice how 120 dB is really much; within a 50 kHz bandwidth, you get -127 dBm of thermal noise; if you amplify that by 120 dB, you make 0.2 mW of pure noise output power. At that point it becomes really questionable an open loop broadband amplifier is useful for anything!

Comment: **So, please edit your question and explain what the application and its requirements** for this 120 dB open loop amplifier are.

Comment: So, is it possible to increase the gain of the frequencies around 50hz - 25khz with an op amp? I have edit my question. Sorry for forgetting to mention the reason. I want to make a noise generator as a special sound effect.

Comment: you can't change the open loop response of an IC opamp. It is what it is. You reduce its gain using feedback and tailor the FB network to shape the closed loop response. (Some opamps have a compensation terminal, in that case you need to look at the datasheet to see what it does.)

Comment: Hmm, what are some of the ways to have the gain of frequencies from 50 hz to 25 khz at 120 dB if we can't change the frequency response of an open loop op amp? I have seen frequency responses of some guitar effect pedals and amplifiers where the frequency responses and gain are more varied.

Comment: It sounds like an XY problem to me. You want to achieve something (that you are not saying) and, propose a solution but, that solution sounds like a bad idea to the experts. If you just want an amplifier that has flat gain between 25 Hz and 50 Hz and that gain is 120 dB then say so.

Comment: @SnoopyKid sorry for the delay in getting back at you. If you want to generate noise, I think there's way better methods than trying to build something with such massive gain.

Comment: Yes Andy, I want a really high gain amp that has a frequency response where the frequency from 50 hz to 25000 hz maintained a gain of 120 dB. But an amp like that, with 120 dB gain, will be a noise generator.

Comment: Hi Marcus, no it's fine. We, me and my friend, will just make several gain stages of multiple opamps if possible to generate a high gain of 120 dB or more. But what we don't know here is to make the frequency from 50 hz to 25000 hz to be maintained at 120 dB.

Comment: the problem is that it's *really* hard to make such an amplifier be stable and not turn into an unintended oscillator, being fed with noise, so this is the domain of expensive measurement equipment. That's why nobody would build a noise generator like this.

Comment: Oh, yes I literally forgot about it being a noise generator. It is almost impossible for a noise generator to have a flat frequency response. According to https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/M5218AL.html, the M5218AL op amp have a typical gain of 110 dB as we can see in page 2. But it didn't state the maximum gain. Does it mean we can adjust the gain to beyond 120 dB and more?